# Did iPhone Simulator 3.0 break two-finger div scrolling?

Tags: iphone, html, ios-simulator, scroll

I recently upgraded to iPhone Simulator 3.0, and when I do a two-finger scroll on a div (in Safari or UIWebView), it no longer works.

To do a two-finger scroll in iPhone simulator, hold option to get two fingers, hold shift to lock the fingers in place relative to eachother, and then click and drag the div.

You can try scrolling the example div on this page:
http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-div-scroll.php

Can anyone reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

I got someone to reproduce this. Based on that, it seems that Simulator 3.0 did break two-finger div scrolling, but it didn't break on the actual device.